# Optimization using NETLink failing

Tags: mathematical-optimization, .netlink

I define a function called f[x], which gives a numerical result interacting with an external free software called FEMM, using NETLink.

This function works properly and the following codes give the expected result:

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,30},MaxRecursion->0,PlotPoints->30]
```

I try to do some optimization using this function. In order to do that I use

```
NMinimize[f[x],x,Method->"RandomSearch"]
```

But an error appears as below:

**"error: attempt to perform arithmetic on global `x' (a nil value)".**

What could be the cause of this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure without the full definition of `f`, but try defining `ff[x_?NumericQ]:=f[x]` and optimizing `ff` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When added this one, it works and gets the right  result. Thanks a lot. I also feel much sorry for express my gratitude late.